# Improving game load on Unity with big data

Tags: unity-game-engine, bigdata

I'm developing a game for kids with the Unity3d platform. My game has a lot of pictures and images. When I load the game I'm using a Hashset of about 50,000 strings. Each string is a word for each picture I wish the player to see.

What can I do in order to reduce the loading time of the game to a minimum? Currently it takes about 20 seconds just to open the game, without doing anything. 
My project is for Android devices at this moment.

Comment: Is this a web game? Android? iOS? Windows 10?

Comment: Android, thanks for noticing.

Comment: It is not easy. Compressing the pictures as much as you can can help to reduce the package size. And improve a little starting time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is loading the images and data via a web API not a better idea?

Using the [WWW object](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) you can then load the specific files you need at that time. This way you don't have to export the data with the app and keep it really small and fast.